# Taylor and Laurent Series of Complex Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion, laurent-series, singularity

I'm dealing with the function:

$w=\frac{cos(z)}{z^2}$ with $z_0=1$.

I need to find the Taylor and Laurent series expansions about $z_0$ and find their regions on convergence. I'm pretty confused on how to do these, we haven't done anything comparable in class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that the function is analytic except at $z=0$. Hence it will have a Taylor series for $|z-1| <1$ and a Laurent expansion for $|z-1| > 1$.

Comment: @copper.hat Won't the Laurent series equal the Taylor series...?  (Sorry, I'm kind of new to this)  Oh wait, because of poles, so that determines the areas where each converges, right?

Comment: Hm, no, I think that according to how coefficients of a Laurent series are defined, all the negative powers become $0$ and we are left with the Taylor expansion.

Comment: What happens with the cosine on top? Do I just leave that out front as a multiplier?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints:

Note that for $z \neq 0$, $f(z) = {1 \over z^2} - 2 {1 \over z^4} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n {z^n \over (n+2)!}$.

Let $r(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n {z^n \over (n+2)!}$, note that $r$
is entire, and we can write $r(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {r^{(n)}(1) \over n!} (z-1)^n$, with 
$r^{(n)}(1) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n n (n-1)\cdots (n-k+1){1 \over (n+2)!}$

For $|z-1| <1$ we can write
${1 \over z^k} = ( 1+(z-1))^{-k} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-k}{n}(z-1)^n$.

For $|z-1| >1$ we can write
${1 \over z^k} = {1 \over  (1+(z-1))^{k} } = {1 \over (z-1)^k} {1 \over  (1+{1 \over (z-1)) } )^{k} } = {1 \over (z-1)^k} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-k}{n}{1 \over (z-1)^n } $